# Stability of Kotlin Components

Tags: api, kotlin, stability

[Stability of Kotlin Components](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html)

Particularly I'm interested in more details about what "Alpha" means:

```
Alpha means "use at your own risk, expect migration issues":
We decided to productize this idea, but it hasn't reached the final shape yet.
```

I get the 2nd part "expect migration issues" in that there may be binary and api backwards compatibility issues that need to be addressed when updating to a new version of kotlin.

What I don't get is the 1st part, "use at your own risk".

What does that mean?

Should I expect random crashes or bug?

Should I use "Alpha" in a production app?

Comment: "Should I use "Alpha" in a production app?". It is strongly advised against.

Comment: From [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alpha_version), Alpha version: `An early version of a program or application, typically unstable, but useful to show what the product will do. Sometimes this stage is referred to as a preview version. Sometimes no more features are added after this release, but bug fixes continue. This release comes after a pre-alpha version and before a beta version. As opposed to a beta version an alpha version is usually not feature complete.`